# find the angle of point related to pivot

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

It’s been days that I’m working on a project which I have to use convex hull in it, and specific method of graham scan. The problem has been solved till the place I want to sort the points.
So the story is that I have collected bunch of points which they are from the type Point and their coordinates are relatives. Mean they come from the mouse event x and y. So I have collected the mouse positions as x and y of the points. And I want to find the angle related to the pivot point. Does anyone have a piece of code to calculate that angle?
Many and many thanks, the image below is what I need:
[image: Angles over pivote]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
Math.atan2(dy, dx)
```

where `dy` and `dx` represent the vertical and horizontal difference between the point and pivot point.

A few notes to keep in mind:

- The reference (0 radians) is by convention pointing to the right, not to the left as in your image. If you really want to measure it from the left, you'd have to do `Math.PI - angle` to convert it.
- The `Math`-trigonometry functions work in radians. To convert the results to degrees, you can use `Math.toDegrees`.
- In the mathematical world, increasing y-values point upwards. In your image, their pointing downwards.

Comment: Thanks in advanced the algorithm worked very well, just the problem you mentioned is because Java calculate the Y of a point from top left corner of the screen which makes the y increasing when moving down, if I get the abs of the angle it is perfect. 
Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Hmm. I wouldn't use `Math.abs` on the angle though. Then `-45` and `+45` will look the same. Try using `+360` and `% 360` if you want to get rid of negative angles.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the dual-definition of the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to calculate this, as you skip over the nasty point of what happens at vertical lines, and dealing with quadrants

(Forgive my notation as math doesn't work too well in markdown...)

Where `A` and `B` are both 2D vectors with `x` and `y` components, and `theta` is the angle between them:

```
dot(A, B) = ax * bx + ay * by
```

**and**

```
dot(A, B) = |A| * |B| * cos(theta)
```

...where `|A|` is the length of `A`, which can be computed with [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem):

```
|A| = sqrt(ax^2 + ay^2)
```

Therefore:

```
theta = acos((ax * bx + ay * by) / (|A| * |B|))
```

Comment: "as you skip over the nasty point of what happens at vertical lines", or, he could simply use `Math.atan2` which takes care of this for him.

Answer (score 1):

to get the angle from the horizontal of the line linking any two points p1 & p2:
Angle = atan((p1.y - p2.y) / (p1.x - p2.x)

So, your black angle = atan((454-243) / (286-108))
NOTE: y sign reversed as your y axis starts at top-left rather than bottom-left

Angle will be in radians, to convert to degrees muliply by (180/pi)

Comment: Note that by using `atan` you need to manually figure out in which quadrant the angle lies. (Since for instance, `(454-243) / (286-108)` looks the same as when the points are reversed: `(243-454) / (108-286)`.) `Math.atan2` can take care of this for you.