# Problems with projectiles on a 2d plane

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having trouble getting my bullets to go where they want and I was hoping I could get some help identifying where my calculations are off.

Basically I'm making a 2d game and where ever you click on the screen a bullet should shoot at that location that you clicked, but the problem is that my bullets are not going where I want them to. Now I believe my problem is somewhere in the checkScreenForTouch() method and how I'm calculating what should be added to the bullets location. I'm not the best at trigonometry but I do understand it, so if any one has any advice on how to fix the following code that would be super cool :).

```
private void updateBullets(float dt){
    batch.begin();
    for(int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++){
        Bullet b = bullets.get(i);
        b.velocity.x += b.deltaX * b.speed;
        b.velocity.y += b.deltaY * b.speed;
        b.position.x += b.velocity.x * dt;
        b.position.y += b.velocity.y * dt;

        batch.draw(bullTex, b.position.x, b.position.y, bullTex.getWidth(), bullTex.getHeight());
        if(b.position.x < 0 || b.position.x > sWidth || b.position.y < 0 || b.position.y > sHeight){
            bullets.remove(b);
            continue;
        }
    }       
    batch.end();
}

private void checkForScreenTouch(float dt){
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
        Bullet b = new Bullet();
        double angle = Math.atan((p.pos.y - Gdx.input.getY())/(p.pos.x - Gdx.input.getX()));            
        b.deltaX = Math.cos(angle);
        b.deltaY = Math.sin(angle);
        b.position.x = p.pos.x; //sets bullet start position equal to the players
        b.position.y = p.pos.y; 
        bullets.add(b); // array list of bullets
    }
}
```

If you need anything clarified just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Look into [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). That might be what you need.

Comment: Just to check, is bullet speed initialized? Maybe elaborate more on what is the wrong behavior you are currently observing.

Comment: @blufiro With the code above, the bullets will only shoot to the right side of the screen, and it also seems like they are at the opposite angle of what they are suppose to be. And yes the bullet speed is set to a double (speed = 10).

Comment: @JackSullivan That sounds like the issue with just using `atan` for 360 degrees of motion and the change in [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225164/find-the-angle-of-point-related-to-pivot).

Comment: You may want to try destination_position-source_position as the vector. I.e. (Gdx.input.getY()-p.pos.y)/(Gdx.input.getX()-p.pos.x). If they are going to the right of the screen, that usually means your angle is 0 because cos(0) = 1, sin(0) = 0. Do check if your input coordinates are in world space like user2082169 said.

Answer (score 2):

I see you still haven't really gotten any advice on this. Had some time, so I thought I'd whip something up.

The problems you were having I was able to reproduce by using your code.

1. Bullets only shoot to the right - This was solved by using `atan2(dy, dx)`.
2. Opposite angle of what they are supposed to be - This was caused because the calculation `p.pos.y - Gdx.input.getY()` should really have been negated: `Gdx.input.getY() - p.pos.y`. Just a simple mix up. When the mouse has a larger y coordinate than the player location, you'd want the change in y to be positive.

---

Notes about the application:

Some issue with frame resizing. Tends to crop out bullets mid-trajectory.

I divide the change in time by `1000` to signify I want the velocity to be of `pixels/second`. Just a habit thing from physics 20.

The application is in swing. The code you will really want is within the `makeProjectile` function at the top.

Beyond that, I just used a synchronized list to avoid concurrency issues with the updates and the rendering.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * @author Obicere
 */
public class ProjectileTest {

    // It's dangerous to go alone! Take this.
    public void makeProjectile(final MouseEvent e, final int width, final int height){
        final int x = width / 2;
        final int y = height / 2;
        final double angle = Math.atan2(e.getY() - y, e.getX() - x);
        final double deltaX = Math.cos(angle);
        final double deltaY = Math.sin(angle);
        projectiles.add(new Projectile(x, y, deltaX, deltaY));
    }


    private static final double PROJECTILE_VELOCITY = 100; // Pixels per second

    private final Collection<Projectile> projectiles = Collections.synchronizedCollection(new LinkedList<>());

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(ProjectileTest::new);
    }

    public ProjectileTest(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Projectile Test");
        final JPanel content = new JPanel(){

            private final Dimension size = new Dimension(500, 500);

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(final Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawOval(getWidth() / 2 - 2, getHeight() / 2 - 2, 4, 4);
                projectiles.forEach((e) -> e.render(g));
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return size;
            }

        };

        content.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
                makeProjectile(e, content.getWidth(), content.getHeight());
            }
        });

        content.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e) {
                makeProjectile(e, content.getWidth(), content.getHeight());
            }
        });

        final Timer repaint = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final Iterator<Projectile> iter = projectiles.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    final Projectile next = iter.next();
                    if(!next.valid()){
                        iter.remove();
                    }
                    next.step(content.getWidth(), content.getHeight());
                }
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });

        frame.add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        repaint.start();
    }

    public class Projectile {

        private final double velocityX;
        private final double velocityY;

        private double x;
        private double y;

        private long lastUpdate;

        private boolean valid = true;

        public Projectile(final double x, final double y, final double vx, final double vy){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.velocityX = vx;
            this.velocityY = vy;
            this.lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        public boolean valid(){
            return valid;
        }

        public void destroy(){
            this.valid = false;
        }

        public void step(final int width, final int height){
            final long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long change = time - lastUpdate;

            this.x += (change / 1000D) * (velocityX * PROJECTILE_VELOCITY);
            this.y += (change / 1000D) * (velocityY * PROJECTILE_VELOCITY);
            this.lastUpdate = time;

            if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x > width || y > height){
                destroy();
            }
        }

        public void render(final Graphics g){
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawOval((int) x - 2, (int) y - 2, 4, 4);
        }

    }

}
```